# Reading nested collection QueryDSL

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I am using queryDSL to fetch the inner collection of data and failed to do so. My entities are

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "countries")
 @Setter
 @Getter
 public class Country {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long countryId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "data")
    private String data;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "country")
    private State stateJoin;

}
```

2. @Entity
   @Table(name = "states")
   @Setter
   @Getter
   public class State {

   ```
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Column(name = "id")
     private Long stateId;

     @Column(name = "name")
     private String name;

     @Column(name = "count")
     private String count;

     @Column(name = "co_id")
     private Long countryId;

     @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     @JoinColumn(name = "co_id", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
     private Country country;

     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     @JoinColumn(name = "state_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
     private Set<Town> towns;
   ```

   }
3. 

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "towns")
@Setter
@Getter
public class Town {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "town_id")
    private Long townId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "people_count")
    private String peopleCount;

    @Column(name = "st_id")
    private Long stateId;
}
```

and in querydsl i am trying below query and always failing to retrieve inner collection `towns`

```
List<Expression> childGroup = new ArrayList<>();

query.from(countries);

childGroup.addAll(Arrays.asList(countries.name, countries.data, countries.stateJoin));

query.join(countries.stateJoin, State);
childGroup.add(Projections.bean(State.class, name, count, town)
                .as((Path) countries.stateJoin));

        
            OR
            
childGroup.add(Projections.bean(State.class, name, count, list(town)).as((Path) countries.stateJoin));

query.select(fields);
query.where();


final Map<? extends Number, ? extends Object> t =
        (Map<? extends Number, ? extends Object>)
            query
                .limit(pageRequest.getPageSize())
                .offset(pageRequest.getOffset())
                .distinct()
                .transform(
                    GroupBy.groupBy(groupByPath)
                        .as(Projections.bean(Countris.class, childGroup.toArray(new Expression[0]))));
```

while executing the above line exactly i am getting always SQLSyntax error as i see the underlying SQL is with

```
. as towns
```

Can some one help me how to read the nested collection formed by JPA join?